# When do we should use abstract function or normal function in base class in PHP?

Tags: php, oop, inheritance, overriding, abstract

So I have a question about the difference between **"when we should declare normal function"** and **"when we should declare abstract function"** in base class. Look at my example.

**In the abstract class:**

```
abstract class Birds {
    abstract public function fly();
}

class Swallow extends Birds {
    public function fly() {
        // This function override fly function in Birds class
        echo "Implement fly function in Swallow class";
    }
}
```

**In the normal class:**

```
class Birds {
    public function fly() {
        echo "Implement fly function in Birds class";
    }
}

class Swallow extends Birds {
    public function fly() {
        // This function override fly function in Birds class
        echo "Implement fly function in Swallow class";
    }
}
```

What you can see. The fly function in Swallow class is inherited by Birds class (in all cases). They are a same thing. So I'm embarrassed and I dont know when we should declare abstract function in base class?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHP - if all methods in abstract class are abstract then what is the difference between interface and abstract class](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37437633/php-if-all-methods-in-abstract-class-are-abstract-then-what-is-the-difference)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Abstract functions are actually only an interface. E.g. there's no difference in your example between abstract class  and if it would be an interface (that's because there's only abstract method).

```
//abstract class
abstract class Birds {
    abstract public function fly();
}
//interface
interface Birds {
    public function fly();
}
```

That's because abstract methods have the same purpose that interface's method. When you somewhere else create a function (or method or a class or another interface etc.), and you will require any `Birds` instance, you will be sure you have that abstract method avaiable, although it was not implemented in `Birds`.

```
public function sendBirdToSpace(Birds $bird) { //no matter what Bird subclass
    $bird->fly(); //you're sure this method is avaiable
}
```

Also usually you will have more than one child class. When it comes to that, it's getting more clear about abstract method.

It's actually pretty simple. Should `Birds` have a default behaviour implementation of `fly`ing? That's all. If every bird should can fly, but there's no default method - make it abstract.

Comment: Hi @dragoste, It's really a good explanation. Thanks so much. But I have a question in your explanation. What happen If I declare a Penguin class? They can not fly but the flying function is had to defined in Penguin class. So  I'm really embarrassed when I analyze this class.

Comment: I thought the same thing. That's why I said ***if** every bird should can fly*. Alternatively if it's just an exception from the rule, use can throw Exception('Not implemented'), but in this case you have to be prepared to handle this exception anywhere use invoke `fly()`. Another way to handle it could be to use interfaces. Here it would be `FlyingBird` interface that has method `fly()`, and this method would not be in `Birds` class anymore.

Answer (score 3):

Taken from [PHP OOP Class Abstraction](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.abstract.php):

> When inheriting from an abstract class, all methods marked abstract in
>   the parent's class declaration must be defined by the child;
>   additionally, these methods must be defined with the same (or a less
>   restricted) visibility. For example, if the abstract method is defined
>   as protected, the function implementation must be defined as either
>   protected or public, but not private.

This is essentially saying that your `Swallow` class **has** to inherit (*have*) the `fly()` method in it if it extends the `Bird` class based off of its `abstract` definition.

The general rule of thumb when harnessing `abstract` methods is when you want normality among classes.

Take the following for example:

```
Class Car {

    abstract public function make();
    abstract public function model();
}
```

<sup>*This is our "base" class. Anything that extends from this* ***has*** *to* specify the `make()` & `model()` methods.</sup>

```
Class Tesla extends Car {

    public function make() {}

    public function mmodel() {}
}
```

<sup>*As you see above, our `Tesla` class has the required methods within. If you do not include these methods, you'll have PHP errors thrown.*</sup>

---

### Note

If you're exploring this option of "container" like development, then I'd suggest that you have a good look at [PHP OOP Object Interfaces](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.interfaces.php) too, well worth it!